# Creating network dataset for train lines with points representing train stations in ArcGIS Network Analyst?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, network-analyst, network-dataset

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.2, I would like to build a network dataset that that includes a line shapefile representing train lines and a point shapefile indicating train stations along those lines. When I right-click on the Personal Geodatabase I'm working in, and select "Create a Network Dataset," the only shapefiles that show up to be selected for inclusion in the Network Dataset are the line shapefiles within the Personal Geodatabse, but not the point shapefile I would like to use for train stations in the dataset.  Here are some screenshots:

[image: Personal GDB in TOC] [image: Network Dataset dialog box]

Is it possible to include points within a Network Dataset like this?

I thought I was able to do so before, but for some reason I seem unable to include the train stations along with the train lines.

Comment: Yes, point features can be added as junctions to a NDS. I note that none of your point layers or your CTA_Routes_1 layer are showing up. Since they're all already in the FDS that would indicate they're in the same CRS. Have you run Integrate to ensure all of the layers have shared vertices as necessary? Note, those are feature classes, not shapefiles (which wouldn't work). Note that you only need to load them to the NDS if they are to serve as multi-modal junctions. If they're just locations/stops, they gets added as part of the actual analysis and not the NDS.

Comment: That *is* weird. I vaguely remember putting barriers, sources, sinks and stop points on a hydrological network in 9.3.1 but when I tried this on some random data I have lying around the points didn't show up. This may be a bug that Esri support may be interested in. The default junctions are created but barriers/stop points/sources/sinks can't be added. Can you show the properties of ctaBus_ND with the points included? Neither in Geometric Network or Network Dataset.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I was seeing something similar in some tutorial data I have on hand - some layers in the FDS were listed to add to the NDS, some were not. The only thing I could find skimming tutorials was a section to ensure there were coincident vertices in both the line and point layer. I remember successfully doing the tutorial, so I must have gotten it all added at some point. I stepped through the NDS creation and didn't see anything special about making it multi-modal, though I did note you could later add more layers to the NDS *after* creation. Not sure if that would solve it.

Comment: I tried that @ChrisW, the layers that were available at creation were available to include later (minus the ones that were already included). I have dredged up the network I created previously and seen the sources/sinks/junctions included. I will try to export the raw data to a new database and see if the points come up then. Update: copying the features to a new database the points were available what's up with that???

Comment: OK, I found out why the points didn't come up, because they were MULTIPOINT features - not points, which cannot participate in a geometric network http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=1733&t=228177 and presumably a network dataset also. Please check your points are not multipoint (you can make multipoint into points using Multipart to Single part http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003r000000)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson A possible explanation for the new database making them available is database version, and might also explain the issue as a whole (multi-points aside). I noted my tutorial data is in 9.2 whereas when I *did* the tutorial and created new databases and such it was in 10.1. Since I was only looking at the historic stuff, and you were looking at old 9.3 data, I'm wondering if it's simply a database/FDS/NDS *version* issue and upgrading/updating (whichever term the dialog uses) them to 'current' would solve it.

Comment: I thought it might be sort of a topology issue, where the points weren't lining up with the lines. I tried running Integrate as @ChrisW suggested, but found the same issue when trying to add the points to the GDB. Ultimately, it shouldn't be an issue since I can still do my analysis with the points as they are outside of the GDB (also as noted by @ChrisW) but I will also check to see if they are multipoint features and run Multipart to Single.

Comment: That thought had crossed my mind @ChrisW, to be sure I imported the features into a new feature dataset using feature class to feature class (multiple) to bring everything up to the current version. Regardless of whether the points were snapped or not (mine certainly weren't) or even empty features, the only points that were unavailable were those *already* participating in a network (or topology I assume) as a feature class can only participate in one topology or network but I can't find where I read that.

Comment: Wait, you're using points *outside* the gdb? I was making an assumption that the points you were trying to add were the MetraStations_1 layer. Anything that is to participate in a network dataset (that's the dataset, **not** an analysis) *must* reside in the same Feature Dataset. And in order to be in a Feature Dataset, everything must be in the same coordinate system. If you're trying to use points outside a gdb, either one of those would be primary issues to building a NDS with them.

Comment: No no, the points were in the same feature dataset, I just mistyped earlier. This issue seems to be resolve through the suggestion of @MichaelMiles-Stimson; running Multipart to Single Part allowed for the points to be included in the NDS. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know and glad you got it solved. Now @MichaelMiles-Stimson can turn that into a proper answer you can accept and we can upvote. :)

Comment: Hi @ChrisW, I've tried to combine the comments into an answer, hopefully not missing any of the key points and included a few pictures for readability.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments and with help from ChrisW it was determined that the points were unavailable to participate in the Network because they were of [geometry type multipoint](http://resources.esri.com/help/900/arcgisexplorer/sdk/html/35dfc14d-69fa-5748-1690-7911401b222c.htm) (multiple points for a single row):

> A Multipoint geometry represents an unordered collection of single
> locations in space, and can be used to represent geographical features
> which have multiple single locations but which represent a single
> geographical feature, for example the multiple entrances to a single
> rabbit warren

Which cannot participate in a network, according to the help document for creating a [geometric network](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015t000000):

> Only point and line feature classes are supported as input. The
> feature classes cannot participate in another geometric network or
> other advanced geodatabase dataset such as a topology, network
> dataset, terrain, or fabric.

Datsets will be unavailable to include in a network if:

- The feature class is not in the same feature dataset or external to
  the database.
- The feature class participates in a database Topology.
- The feature class is already in another network (either [network
  dataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000007000000) or [geometric network](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002r00000001000000))
- The geometry type is not point or line

To convert multipoint features into point features use the [Multipart to Single Part](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003r000000) geoprocessing tool.

In catalog it is difficult to discern a multipoint from a point:

[image]

Even though I know that POINTFEATURES are points and REVTABLEPOINT are multipoint features they look identical. You must right click on the dataset and get the properties to find out if the features are point or multipoint.

Multipoint features:

[image: Example of multipoint]

Point Features:

[image: Example of point]

I have seen that when data is imported from MapInfo TAB and some CAD formats the points will be imported as multipoints, mostly with a single point for each row, to avoid the possible loss of geometry during import.